# Why is $T:\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $T(0,y) = 0 \implies y = 0$ linear?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a linear transform that makes this:

$T(0,y)=0 \Rightarrow y=0$

a) Show that, given $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there is only one $y=f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $T(x,f(x))=0$.

b) Show that the function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ obtained in item a is linear.

Here is how I made item a:
Let $y_1,y_2$ such that $T(x,y_1)=0=T(x,y_2)$. $T$ is linear, then $T(x,y_1)-T(x,y_2)=0 \Rightarrow T(x-x,y_1-y_2)=0 \Rightarrow T(0,y_1-y_2)=0$. By definition of $T$, $y_1-y_2=0 \Rightarrow y_1=y_2$.

Is this correct?

Also, I have no idea how to make item b.

Thanks.

Comment: For part a) you are missing the existence of $y$. You only showed uniqueness under the assumption of existence. For part b) you have to check $f(x_1+x_2)=f(x_1)+f(x_2)$ and $f(\lambda\,x) = \lambda\,f(x)$.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: @Cristoph but isn´t the uniqueness a necessary and sufficient condition for the existence in this case? how can I show existence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any linear transformation $T: \mathbb R^{2} \to \mathbb R$ is of  the form $T(x,y)=ax+by$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb R$.  The given condition implies that $b \neq 0$. The unique $f(x)$ such that $T(x,f(x))=0$ is give by $ax+b(f(x))=0$ or $f(x)=-\frac  a b x$. Hence $f$ is linear.